# Check if columns is visible in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a button in the excel bar that automatically show/hide the first column in all the sheets in my workbook. 
My question is: is there a way to execute an action (different for every sheets) according to the visibility of the column?
I'd like that every time the column turns visible/unvisible an action get executed automatically.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.hidden`

```
If Columns("A").Hidden = True Then
           MsgBox "Column A not visible"
           Columns("A").Hidden = False ' will unhide your column
           MsgBox "Column A visible"
End If
```

To resume :

**Check if Column Hidden** : `If Columns("A").Hidden = True Then`

**Check if Column UnHidden** : `If Columns("A").Hidden = False Then`

If you have any other question do not hesitate

Comment: Thanks but how can I automatically check? I mean is there a method/observer that triggers a functions every time the column get visible/unvisible?

Comment: @FrancescoBordignon you can do this when you open the workbook would it help you or you are looking for an other way ? `Private Sub Workbook_Open()`should i edit my answer with this way or you aren't interested by this way

Comment: When do you want to check automatically if the column is visible? Check the following workbook events: Workbook_SheetActivate, Workbook_SheetChange, Workbook_SheetSelectionChange